# Why is volatile necessary in Java

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, volatile, cpu-cache

In Java, all threads uses the same heap. If a thread is caching the operations to the heap, when exactly will it flush to heap?

I have read so many posts but not able to find the answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` tells Java that the variable may change in multiple threads, and so not to cache the variable. Caching is a processor level construct, and so the processor may flush the cache whenever it wants.

Comment: when I change the variable in object it will not change immediately the processor will decide.. is it? this volatile will instruct the processor to flush the contents to heap memory ?

Comment: "Flush the contents" implies the write-side of caching. Volatile refers to both the write side AND the read side. Basically, the processor must not keep a copy of the variable inside of a register or cache, but rather must read from RAM each and every time the variable is used.

Comment: Since this has the only upvote I have two comments.  1.  Volatile does not mean that a thread must read and write directly from memory.  All it says is that each thread must have the most up to date value of the field.  This can be achieved without going directly to memory via cache coherence.  2. Volatile also defines strict rules for read/write ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Giving other example: There are websites like **Stock websites** which want to show the users the **most recent data** and not some **stale** data. Right?

So what they do is that they **disable caching of webpages** so that the pages will not be cached anywhere and all will get the most recent data updated.

Similar is the case with `volatile`, cores or processors have their **own caches** and they cache the result thinking that the thread running on current processor does not change the value of a variable then why should it go and read from **memory** again and again. So it caches it and returns the cached value (**This is for hardware level performance**).

So if like the website example you want to **stop** other processors using stale values you need to **stop caching** and `volatile` is the way to do that in Java.

Comment: The code itself can "cache" the variable as well, by using a previously fetched value.  It's a relatively common optimization, and works if you can assume the value will only be changed by the current code (which is the usual case).  *This* is the main thing `volatile` has always been designed to prevent.  The cross-processor synchronization is relatively new (as of 1.5), and was added mostly because that's how people assumed it worked all along.